# Separate hsv channels in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, hsv

I am having an hsv mat file in opencv and I want to separate the channels. I found  cvSplit( hsv, h, s, v, NULL ), but it doesn't work with Mat files. How is it then, to keep just the first channel h of  from the Mat image file??
My result is the above. Basically is the image that I convert, I can see the face but in weird tones.

[image: h channel]

The code used:

```
    cvtColor(cropped_rgb, cropped_hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
    split(cropped_hsv, channels);
    cropped_hsv = channels[0]; 
    imshow("cropped_hsv", cropped_hsv);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply use [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split):

```
Mat hsv;
vector<Mat> channels;
split(hsv, channels);
```

channels[0], channels[1], channels[2] will contain your H, S, V respectively.

Comment: imshow("h channel",channels[0]); I get as result a weird image. Is it due to convertion??

Comment: OK basically I think value channel is closer to a gray_scale image, which is actually what I want.

Comment: here are different color models and their channels: http://blog.patdavid.net/2012/12/getting-around-in-gimp-black-and-white30.html