# How to flip a cv::mat in c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I have a cv::mat with 3 layers, and I want to switch between the first and the last layers.
Some thing like this:(matlab style)

```
cv::mat mt = image;
mt = [mt[:,:,2],mt[:,:,1],mt[:,:,0]];
```

Comment: Layer = channel/dimension? Use cv::split

Comment: can you give a full answer? I don't understand

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split

Comment: The answere here should work for other imafe types too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014626/separate-hsv-channels-in-opencv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More polished ifryed's solution:

```
#include <algorithm>

cv::Mat im = getImage();
std::vector<cv::Mat> img_rgb;
cv::split(im,img_rgb);
std::iter_swap(img_rgb, img_rgb+2); 
cv::merge(img_rgb,im);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        cv::Mat im = getImage();
        cv::Mat tmp = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(im.rows,im.cols),CV_8UC1);
        std::vector<cv::Mat> img_rgb;
        cv::split(im,img_rgb);

        img_rgb[0].copyTo(tmp);
        img_rgb[2].copyTo(img_rgb[0]);
        tmp.copyTo(img_rgb[2]);
        cv::merge(img_rgb,im);
```

Comment: That should work! But I think you don't have to use copyTo(). Simply assignment will do the trick since we don't need to copy image contents, their headers are sufficient, e.g. after split just   do tmp = img_rgb[0]; img_rgb[0] = img_rgb[2]; img_rgb[2] = tmp; .Moreover, I think using iter_swap(img_rgb, img_rgb+2) from <algorithm> will be nice there