# Efficient bitwise AND on the channels of a Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I need a bitwise AND on all (3) channels of a matrix
and tried this way:

```
Mat img(5,5,CV_8UC3);
Mat chTmp, chRes;

extractChannel(img, chTmp, 0);
extractChannel(img, chRes, 1);
bitwise_and(chTmp, chRes, chRes);
extractChannel(img, chTmp, 2);
bitwise_and(chTmp, chRes, chRes);
```

But extractChannel seems to allocate/ copy (?) the contents of the channels,
which is costly.

Is there a better way? E.g. only *access/ address* the 3 channels when building chRes, without a tmp channel?

Comment: Have you tried cv::split? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014626/separate-hsv-channels-in-opencv

Comment: Yes, as far as I know split copies too. But for my purpose that's unnecessary. I only need the access to be able to do the and operation.

Comment: Just write your own loop, and if you want to parallelize it, implement a derived class of [`ParallelLoopBody`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d2/d74/classcv_1_1ParallelLoopBody.html). You won't find a pre-made solutions for every conceivable operation.

Comment: OpenCV Mats are limited in the striding they can do. they might not be able to model suitable "views" on this data.

Comment: @DanMašek: Well spoken indeed! Would it eventually be within your reach to sketch the idea of specific loops in more detail master? Actually I doubt that there is a more efficient way than the simple copy one.

Comment: Yeah, that performance difference there is quite interesting. I really don't feel like digging through the rather complex implementation right now. I have a feeling though that by copying out the the individual channels, you get a memory layout (all the relevant values packed together) that allows a very fast vectorized implementation of `bitwise_and` to be dispatched. `extractChannel` is probably optimized for those common scenarios as well. On the other hand, the "read every 3rd" approach only works with a less efficient implementation.

Comment: Hand-written single pass implementation would be done (using SIMD intrinsics) similar to how you would vectorize conversion from RGB to grayscale, except that after de-interlacing you'd do the bitwise logical operation. I mean, I can see a way to get there, but it's definitely a fair amount of work. | Your approach is already good enough, and if you need to do that repeatedly, just re-use the temporary arrays between iterations.

Comment: @DanMašek: OK then, that's what I was suspecting (with my very limited experiences in OpenCV).
But about your hint of re-using temporary arrays: I learned that most of OpenCV's functions do their parameters by value (first of all they allocate "Src_" and "_Dest" on their own). So it wouldn't have any effect providing pre-allocated parameters?

Comment: wrong assumption. it would. it's not by value. Mat does reference-counting. every time you "copy" a Mat, the data is shared between the original and the copy Mat. only when you `.clone()` do you actually copy data. passed-in allocated Mats have to match perfectly or else they'll be resized. getting this right is trivial though.

Comment: It might look like that on first sight, e.g. `void cv::extractChannel(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int coi)`... until you notice that, say, `OutputArray` is a typedef for `const _OutputArray&`. `_OutputArray` and friends are proxy classes that allow you to use a number of different types to represent the data (not just `Mat`), without bloating the API with gazillion overloads. Constructors of those proxies take arguments by reference and hold the data object in a void pointer. (And on top there's the stuff Christoph mentions).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, using `cv::Mat::reshape()` and `cv::Mat::col()` will be able to avoid data copy to extract channels.

But I don't know this is efficient or not.

```cpp
cv::Mat Src( 2,2, CV_8UC3 );
Src.at<cv::Vec3b>( 0,0 ) = cv::Vec3b( 0b0000'0000u, 0b0000'0001u, 0b0000'0010u );   // result should be 0000'0000 (=0)
Src.at<cv::Vec3b>( 0,1 ) = cv::Vec3b( 0b0000'1000u, 0b1000'1001u, 0b0000'1010u );   // result should be 0000'1000 (=8)
Src.at<cv::Vec3b>( 1,0 ) = cv::Vec3b( 0b1111'0000u, 0b0111'1001u, 0b0011'0000u );   // result should be 0011'0000 (=48)
Src.at<cv::Vec3b>( 1,1 ) = cv::Vec3b( 0b1111'1111u, 0b1111'1111u, 0b1111'1110u );   // result should be 1111'1110 (=254)

cv::Mat Result;
{
    cv::Mat Src_ = Src.reshape( 1, 2*2 ); //This header interprets the Src.data as {1ch, 4rows, 3cols}.
    cv::Mat Result_;
    cv::bitwise_and( Src_.col(0), Src_.col(1), Result_ );
    cv::bitwise_and( Src_.col(2), Result_, Result_ );
    Result = Result_.reshape( 1, 2 );
}

std::cout << Result << std::endl;  //(output is [0,8; 48,254])
```

Comment: Good thinking. However, one disadvantage of this that will become noticeable with bigger arrays is that it has to do two passes to calculate the result.

Comment: Two passes of what, please? My code needs two bitwise_and too, and the reshape is O(1).

Comment: I compared both solutions with a 36 MP RGB image. The reshape solution takes more than double as long, but uses a bit less mem.

Comment: @User42 "Two passes of what, please?" -- both the input and output arrays.

Comment: Umm... who wrote this answer is me, but I don't understand clearly why this way becomes very slow yet. Is it due to memory access locations is not continuous?

Comment: Yes, I don't get it either, it should be the other way round.
Your proposal has 2 non-continuous accesses, and mine even 3 of them!
bitwise_and at continuous and reshape are about "for free" I might think?
Confused I am.